# How to remove horizontal grid lines and get plain white background on ROC graph

Tags: plot, graph, stata, roc, gridlines

I am conducting a ROC curve analysis in Stata. However, I am having trouble with the commands needed to get a plain white background plot.

I would like to:

1. remove the faint horizontal grid lines in the plot
2. remove the blue fill outside of the plot region
3. move the legend to the right upper-hand side (without a border/fill)

The following command was used to generate the ROC curve for a nonparametric ROC analysis without covariates:

`roctab outcomedeath biomarkerlevel, binomial graph rlopts(lcolor(none) lpattern(shortdash)) legend(on)`

Comment: There is no data or graph example here and no indication of what scheme you are using, but the question about blue fill suggests that you are using the default `s2color` and the easiest move is to use some other scheme. There are many community-contributed schemes, but an official scheme such as `s1color` may help. Otherwise you need to consult the help on `axis label options` and `legend options`.

Answer (score 1):

As Nick implied, providing a reproducible example is the best way to help others on SO to help you.

Nevertheless, using the example from the `roctab` help file, we can see the standard Stata graph would look something like this:

```
webuse hanley, clear
roctab disease rating, graph
```

[image]

I like to use the scheme `cleanplots` (authored by Trenton Mize), which you can install with the command:

```
net install cleanplots, from("https://tdmize.github.io/data/cleanplots")
```

You can then either set it as your permanent scheme, or call it explicitly when you call your graph. For example:

```
* Option 1: set to cleanplots permanently (or until I change to something else)
set scheme cleanplots, perm 

* Option 2: set to cleanplots just for this session
set scheme cleanplots

*Option 3: call cleanplots explicitly by adding this option when you call your graph
, scheme(cleanplots)
```

You can then run the graph command, which will give you something like this:

```
roctab disease rating, graph scheme(cleanplots) //i'm assuming you went with Option 3
```

[image]

I personally think this cleans up the graph significantly (removing the blue fill around the plot, adding a bit more space between y-axis and x-axis titles and their corresponding axes, rotating the ylabels so they're more easily readable, etc.). To then get the other two items you want (moving the legend and removing the faint gridlines), you just need to add in a few more options:

```
roctab disease rating, graph legend(on ring(1) row(2) pos(2)) ylab(, nogrid) xlab(, nogrid)
```

[image]

Note the above removes both horizontal and vertical grid lines, but if you only want to remove the horizontal ones just delete the bit that reads `xlab(, nogrid)`. And if you want to move the legend onto the plotregion (it's currently outside of it, [see p.3 of this documentation](https://www.stata.com/manuals/g-3region_options.pdf#g-3region_options)), you should change the value of `ring()` from `1` to `0`.

Finally it's worth noting that whenever a help file says that you can pass through [twoway_options](https://www.stata.com/manuals/g-3twoway_options.pdf) which the `roctab` help file does, you can use any twoway options. I accept that still leaves a lot of room for error and discovery, but still thought it was worth mentioning.

Comment: Thank you so much! The example that you provided was really helpful as well. I tried this code and it worked for me.

Comment: sure thing. glad it helped. you can upvote it, and if it answers your question you can accept it as the answer